# Non-diffeomorphic but homeomorphic (under Lorentzian topology) Lorentzian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

$\newcommand{\lorentzian}{\mathrm{lorentzian}}\newcommand{\lorentzian}{\mathrm{lorentzian}}\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{diff}}\newcommand{\manifold}{\mathrm{manifold}}$Take a time-oriented Lorentzian manifold $(M, g)$ that is not [strongly causal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality_conditions).

The Lorentzian metric $g$, however can define a topology, that is strictly coarser than that of the manifold topology. Say: $\tau_{\lorentzian} \subsetneqq \tau_{\manifold}$.

The topology can be found at this post: [Lorentzian Topology](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266912/503363)

Assume I have two Lorentzian time-oriented manifolds $(M_1,g_1)$, $(M_2,g_2)$ that are not strongly causal, but are homeomorphic **under their Lorentzian topologies**
$(M_1, \tau_{\lorentzian}) \cong (M_2, \tau_{\lorentzian} )$.

***My 1st question:***

Is it possible that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not diffeomorphic as differentiable manifolds (**with the manifold topology and NOT the Lorentzian topology**) $(M_1, \diff) \not\equiv (M_2, \diff) $ while $(M_1, \tau_{\lorentzian}) \cong (M_2, \tau_{\lorentzian} )$ as topological spaces?

***My 2nd question:***

Is it possible for the $\tau_{\lorentzian}$ not to be antidiscrete?

**NOTE**: **the differential structure in $(M, \diff)$ is exactly the one underlying the Lorentzian manifold.**

**NOTE**: **to be more physically sound, one can name the $\tau_{lorenzian}$ topology, also $\tau_{observers}$ topology.**

Even an example of such a scenario would be extremely of use!

---

**Physical motivation:**

If such distinct differentiable manifolds that induce the same topology via their Lorentzian metric exist, one can define an entropy for the Lorentzian topology by counting the distinct diffeomorphism classes say $w$ and write $S=k_B \ln(w) $ by Boltzmann's relation. And causality will be emergent rather than fundamental, so to speak.

**This can potentially give rise to a cosmological arrow of time or entropic time if not also quantum non-locality in case one interprets the differential and topological degrees of freedom as the Hidden Variables of Quantum Mechanics!**

Comment: I dont know anything about this, but in the question you linked there is an example where the topology is the indiscrete topology. If you cook up another non-diffeomorphic manifold with this property, which shouldnt be too hard, you will have your example

Comment: @ThomasRot: the example given works with $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n \geq 1$ (the spatial part can have arbitrary dimensions). So just take $M_1$ and $M_2$ two such manifolds with distinct dimensions.

Comment: @WillieWong very interesting. But given that the topology is quite extreme case, I just am afraid this can not be generalized to more generic(physically friendly! or common sense) topologies. In Physics generic observers(read neighbourhoods as a mathematician) are local(mostly in its strict sense) and not global.

Comment: It appears your question has been answered in the comments.  Would you agree?

Comment: @RyanBudney Actually in a formal sense yes. But I'd like to have more realistic instances. A 4-manifold maybe. The topology in case of the former example is very extreme case. That really brothers me from a physical point of view.

Comment: I find it impossible to understand what the "Lorentzian topology" is from the link with that name.

Comment: @DanielAsimov https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/228676/181792

Comment: @DanielAsimov: the causal relation defined by  "$p \prec q$ iff there is a timelike curve joining $p$ to $q$ with $p$ in the past of $q$" is a preorder on any time-oriented Lorentzian manifold. The "Lorentzian topology" is the Alexandrov topology for this preorder.

Comment: It seems to me that the mathematical question has been answered as posed. The shift of the focus by the OP to "Boltzmann entropy via counting diffeomorphism classes" seems to me highly problematic, in the sense of implicitly relying on some highly speculative ideas from physics. Hence the downvote.

Comment: Can you please clarify the problems with the diffeomorphism classes as microstates? @IgorKhavkine

Comment: The problem is that until you can formulate a meaningful mathematical question about it, that kind of discussion doesn't belong on MathOverflow. That's all that I'll say here.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine that's merely the physical motivation behind the mathematical question. You cannot make sense of it, so ignore it. I prefer to help the reader having an idea about the importance of the question.

Comment: @BastamTajik: As far as having $4$-manifolds, this seems trivial: given any connected Riemannian manifolds $M,N$, $S^1\times M$ and $S^1\times N$ have the obvious Lorentzian structure which makes the Lorentzian topology antidiscrete, making the two homeomorphic (since they both have the cardinality of the continuum). I'm not sure if $M,N$ not being diffeomorphic is sufficient for $S^1\times M$ and $S^1\times N$ not to be diffeomorphic either, but this is definitely true for example if they have distinct fundamental groups.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks alot. I wonder if there's any nontrivial case in which the topology is not antidiscrete. Or can one show that the topology is always antidiscrete?

Comment: @BastamTajik: You can get such examples as outlined in Willie's answer. Just take any Lorentzian $M$ which has a closed timelike curve, but such that the Lorentzian topology is nontrivial (plus maybe it is "not too crazy", for example, $\pi_1(M)$ not being isomorphic to $\pi_1(M)*\pi_1(N)$ for some connected manifold $N$ with boundary $S^{n-1}$ should suffice) yields such examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to argue that the situation considered [in the](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453657/non-diffeomorphic-but-homeomorphic-under-lorentzian-topology-lorentzian-manifo?noredirect=1#comment1173719_453657) [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453657/non-diffeomorphic-but-homeomorphic-under-lorentzian-topology-lorentzian-manifo?noredirect=1#comment1174040_453657) is "close to generic".

Let $(M,g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold that is not strongly causal; this implies that $(M,g)$ is also not stably causal, and hence a small perturbation of it will admit a closed time-like curve. We may therefore assume *generically* that our $(M,g)$ admits a closed time-like curve $\gamma$.

Choose $p\in \gamma$, we have therefore $\gamma\subset I^+(p)$ and $\gamma\subset I^-(p)$; hence the set $U_\gamma = I^+(p) \cap I^-(p)$ is non-empty, and must be contained in every "Lorentzian neighborhood" of $p$. In particular, the "Lorentzian topology" must be non-Hausdorff.

As $\gamma$ is compact, it has a tubular neighborhood within $U_\gamma$ that is topologically $\mathbb{S}^1 \times B^n$ where $n$ is the spatial dimension. Let $t\in \mathbb{S}^1$ and $x\in B^n$ provide a set of coordinates for this tubular neighborhood; we can arrange for $\partial_t$ to be time-like on this neighborhood.

Now take an $n$-dimensional manifold $D$ with boundary, whose boundary is $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, with non-trivial topology. Equip $D$ with a Riemannian metric. Carve out the tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$ and replace it (smoothly glue in) a copy of $\mathbb{S}^1\times D$, equipped with the product Lorentzian metric.

As this modification is entirely within $U_\gamma$, and one easily sees that for every $q_1, q_2\in \mathbb{S}^1\times D$, there exists a time-like curve connecting the two, we see that the Lorentzian topology of the modified manifold is the same as the original. But as long as $M$ doesn't have too crazy a topology the modified manifold should not be diffeomorphic to the original.

Comment: In particular, I don't think you can "count the number of distinct diffeomorphism classes".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need time to reflect. But for the moment let me ask Why exactly you don't think one can not count the classes? There might be infinities of different cardinalities for different classes. Also a sort of density of diff structure can be defined, since not all dimensions admit the same cardinality for the number of diff structures.

Comment: My comment is specifically based on your discussion about entropy, for which the count would only make sense were it finite.

Comment: In classical statistical Mechanics there's continuum of microstates in the phase space. So many examples. As far as one can introduce some weight function in the partition function, that's ok

Comment: is the Lorentzian topology non-Hausdorff or it is not Hausdorff? To me non-Hausdorff means no two points can be dinstinguished.

Comment: @BastamTajik: That is very weird terminology. When no two points can be distinguished, the topology is usually called one of: trivial, indiscrete, antidiscrete. Anyway, in this answer, clearly it means that it is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @tomasz Don't you think I can assume in general those manifolds that agree topologically everywhere outside to CTC contaning tubes. In other words, carving out all the $U_{\gamma}$s and imposing strong causality on the rest of the manifold so the two topologies agree in the remnant of the manifold?

Comment: @tomasz to put it more formally: take the subspace $\overline{M} = M - U_{\gamma}$. Is it possible for the $\tau_{lorenzian}$ and $\tau_{manifold}$ to agree on 
$\overline{M}$ with their subspace topologies, and be still different in $U_{\gamma}$?

Comment: @BastamTajik: I don't see why not, but my knowledge of Lorentzian geometry is rather superficial, so I cannot really say that with any degree of confidence.

Comment: @WillieWong can you please reflect on my last two comments, it would be a favor. Thanks

Comment: @Bastam  How are you defining $U_\gamma$? In my answer $U_\gamma$ may be a strict subset of $I^+(\gamma) \cap I^-(\gamma)$ and hence do not exhaust all problematic points. In terms of "is it possible" the answer is obviously yes, and you can cook up easy examples. But I suppose your question is more "is it always the case"? In this case you need to make a much more precise definition.

Comment: For example, I can easily imagine a setting where a point $p$ does not belong on any closed timelike curves, but $\tau_{Lorentzian}$ is still "bad" at $p$. This is related to the fact that strongly causal spacetimes need not be stably causal, and in general, if $N$ is an open subset of $M$, then the "Lorentzian topology of $N$ with respect to the induced metric on $N$" is not necessarily equal to the "subspace topology on $N$ of the Lorentzian topology on $M$".

Comment: Really thanks for both comments, in the last comment does your problematic $p$
 necessarily lie inside of $U_γ=I^+ {(q)} ∩I^− {(q)} $ for some $q∈ \gamma$
? @WillieWong

Comment: if $p\in I^+(q) \cap I^-(q)$ then necessarily there is a closed timelike curve through $p$.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I exactly asked in my lastest comment. Actually I want to write a set which accounts for all such aforementioned problematic $p$
 **even up to perturbation**. Would it be $\bigcup_{q∈γ} U_q$
 where $U_q=I^+(q)∩I^−(q)$
 @WillieWong

Comment: I should confess, maybe you have no idea how much helpful your reply was to me, but I still am baffled about what you exactly mean by **problematic** and I search for a topological way to account for all of such points. @WillieWong

Comment: forgive me for not willing to devote more time to this: while coming up with weird counterexamples are fun for a while, my normal preference is to work with only globally hyperbolic space-times and at some point this gets too much like actual research, and my energy for that is better used on my actual research problems. // For your question two above: the best definition is just to take the set of all points for which the definition of strong causality fails. Whether there are simpler equivalent definitions I don't know.