# Is this set a manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

Take a general spacetime that **is not strongly causal.**

Call this spacetime $(M, g) $ where $M$ is a connected time-oriented manifold and $g$ is the Lorentzian metric that satisfies the Einstein's Field Equation.

**The topology considered is the manifold topology throughout the whole text which is strictly finer than the [Alexandrov topology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/228676/181792) iff the spacetime is not strongly causal.**

Let $U$, $V$ be open subsets (manifold topology) of a spacetime $(M,g)$, with $V\subset U$. $V$ is called **causally convex** in $U$ if any causal curve contained in $U$ with endpoints in $V$, is entirely contained in $V$.

A point $p$ is called **strongly causal** iff given any neighborhood $U$ (manifold topology) of $p$ there exists a neighborhood $V\subset U$, $p\in V$, such that $V$ is causally convex in $U$.

Call the set of all points that **are not strongly causal** in $(M,g)$ spacetime: $N$.

My question:

What are the general features of such subset $N$? Is it a submanifold of $N$? Is it immersed or embedded or anything at all? Is it Lorentzian in case of being a manifold at all?

Even some hints about what goes on around one such point is very useful.

Comment: While I don't know enough about mathematical pyhsics, I can at least comment that the easiest way to show that a subset $S\subset M$  is a submanifold, is to use the implicit function theorem. Thus we have to write the subset the preimage of a submanifold $N\subset N'$ under some smooth map $f:M\to N'$. Often the submanifold can be written as the solution of a system of equations and thus these equations define $f$ and we are looking at the preimage of $0$. Then one still has to verify the condition on the differential.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you define the interval topology, that would make your question self-contained.

Comment: @RyanBudney I edited the question and changed some terminology which I guess is more explainatory. But thanks for the remark.

Comment: Sorry but there are still some unclear things for me. Under your link, I could not figure out which topology is Alexandrov and which is not. Also I do not know what is a time-oriented manifold

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the Alexandrov topology is called the Lorentzian topology in this link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453657/non-diffeomorphic-but-homeomorphic-under-lorentzian-topology-lorentzian-manifo

Comment: At the very least, we know that $N$ is *closed* since strong causality at a given point is an *open* condition. We also know that $N$, if nonvoid, cannot consist of a single point: for each $p\in N$ there are $q_\pm\in J^{\pm}(p)\smallsetminus\{p\}$ such that $I^\mp(r)\supset I^\mp(q_\pm)$ for all $r\in J^\pm(p)$, which on their turn imply that $q_\pm\in N$ (or course, we could still have $q_+=q_-$). This is argued e.g. in Lemma 4.16 and Remark 4.17, pp. 31-32 of R. Penrose, *Tecniques of Differential Topology in Relativity* (SIAM, 1972).

Comment: very interesting indeed. What do you by **single point**? You mean it can not appear as an isolated point or it should appear as $n>1$ isolated points(if it appears as isolated points at all!)? @PedroLauridsenRibeiro

Comment: (continued) In the previous comment, $I^{+/-}(p)$ and $J^{+/-}(p)$ are respectively the chronological future / past of $p$ and the causal future / past of $p$ in $(M,g)$. Moreover, the interior of $N$ contains all points of $(M,g)$ contained in some closed timelike curve = *vicious* points (the latter forming an open subset) of $(M,g)$, and the boundary of $N$ is ruled by past- or future-inextendible null geodesics. Paragraphs 4.26 though 4.32, pp. 34-38 of R. Penrose, *ibid.* discuss this and other properties of $N$, see also B. Carter, Gen. Rel. Grav. **1** (1971) 349-391.

Comment: No, $N$ cannot have isolated points. This is made clear by the characterization of $N$ provided in my last comment above. This is discussed in more detail in the aforementioned references by Penrose and Carter.