# What is the nerve of this category?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, simplicial-complexes, general-relativity, lorentzian-geometry

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a thin category, we call $U \subseteq \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ open if for every object $X \in U$ and any morphism $X \to Y$, we also have $Y \in U$. This declares an Alexandrov topology on $\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$.

This defines the Alexandrov topology of a preordered set $P=\mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$.

My questions:

What is the nerve of this category?

What would be the geometric/topological realization of such simplicial set( in case it has any!)?

The question is motivated by the Lorentzian metric induced [Alexandrov topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime_topology#:%7E:text=Nowadays%2C%20the%20correct%20mathematical%20term,Alexandrov%20topology%20remains%20in%20use.) of a time-oriented ***not-strongly causal*** sapcetime.

Such view results in turning spacetime into a thin category that I am curious about its structure.

---

I do not know if the manifold topology which is [finer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/266912/503363) than that of the Alexandrov topology can be formulated and linked to this category in any easy way at all. Any such functorial relation would be of great importance to me.

My personal superficial/stupid first step would be to first think of the smooth triangulations of the underlying manifold and only later think of any possible relation (bearing in mind that all smooth manifolds can be triangulated).

Comment: Any (not necessarily triangulable) topological space gives rise to simplicial set, the singular set, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_set

Comment: It was a blunder. Sorry I corrected it. @DonuArapura

Comment: Just reading this question, I have no clue what you're talking about. You are forcing the reader to follow links, which is really not a good idea.

Comment: In many cases, the category is filtered and the nerve of a filtered category is weakly contractible.  For example, this is the case for a Lorentzian manifold with its causality structure.

Comment: Just to make sure I follow you. Are you talking about the neighborhood filter of the Lorentzian manifold Alexandrov topology or the a filter over the thin category mentioned in the question above? Because it doesn't seem very immediate to me if the category is a filtered one (in the second scenario). Because the Alexandrov topology defined over the same set $M$ which is a topological manifold does not necessarily match the manifold topology but it's strictly coarser in our case. Two distinct points might turn indistinguishable by a coarser topology and so on. @DmitriPavlov

Comment: @BastamTajik: Any homotopy type is weakly equivalent to the nerve of a poset and therefore to the nerve of a thin category.  However, for a Lorentzian manifold, under mild restrictions (e.g., stably causal), any two points x, y can be connected by future-directed timelike curves to another point z, which means the relevant poset is filtered and the nerve of the corresponding thin category is weakly contractible.

Comment: But the question is concerned with non-strongly causal case as explicitly mentioned. So I guess this might fail in our case. No? @DmitriPavlov

Comment: @BastamTajik: I don't know what “non-strongly causal” means, and no definition is provided, so it is hard to say more without some concrete details.  I cited the example of strongly causal spacetimes since my guess is that non-strongly causal spacetimes should contain strongly causal spacetimes as a special case.

Comment: Non-strongly causal means it's not strongly causal. @DmitriPavlov

Comment: Dmitri was being conscious of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle

Comment: What is a "thin category"? I suspect it's what I would call a [preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) -- a category $C$ such that for each $x,y \in C$ there is at most one morphism $x \to y$. Is that correct?

Comment: @TimCampion yes absolutely.